Job aligned recurring configuration using Jobrunr
I am trying to write a recurring job that should run on job aligned basis (runs the job after a fixed time from the last job run finish time).
I've observed that JobRunr operates on a clock-aligned schedule (every X interval), and I'm encountering two different behaviors:
Behavior 1:
I have a recurring job scheduled to run every 10 seconds. If the job takes 3 minutes to complete, JobRunr waits for the job to finish and then continues running the job every 10 seconds after that.

Behavior 2:
In this case, I have a job scheduled to run every 2 minutes, and if one run takes 1.5 minutes to complete, the next job starts immediately after 30 seconds (to align with the 2-minute interval).

What I want is to configure JobRunr so that the next job starts a fixed time after the previous job finishes. For example, if a job is scheduled to run every 2 minutes and it takes 1 minute to complete, the next run should happen 2 minutes after the last one finishes. However, I haven't found a way to configure the jobs this way, so they are "job-aligned" rather than clock-aligned.
CODE -

    @Job(name = "AUTH_DATA_TO_S3_JOB")
    @Recurring(id = "RECURRINGAUTHJOB", cron = "${auth.jobtimegap}")
    public void checkAndStartListener() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        AuthRunnableKafkaListener runner = new AuthRunnableKafkaListener(authKafkaConfigProps, authorizationDataService, customObjectMapper, count);
        runner.run();
        count++;
        log.info("total time taken : {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }


application.yaml
org:
  jobrunr:
    background-job-server:
      enabled: true
      poll-interval-in-seconds: 7
    database:
      type: sql
      skip-create: false
      database-name: myapp
    dashboard:
      enabled: false
      port: 9006
auth:
  jobtimegap: "*/2 * * * *"


